# Flash Objects SWF security (ExternalInterface.call)

Tags: xss, flash

I am performing a penetration test against a website that uses Flash.

I found this piece of code:

```
url = ExternalInterface.call("window.document.location.href.toString") as String;
```

How it can be exploited?

I tried to exploit it as XSS via submitting a payload after the #:

```
.swf?id=blabla#payloadhere
```

but nothing. Since I am not really good with Actionscript can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

The ExternalInferface.call() is designed for invoking javascript, so this function as written effectively gives you the opportunity to invoke arbitrary javascript in the execution context of the website, which is already a serious security hole.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001039.html

How specifically to exploit it?  There's a ton of web sites about javascript security holes, you just have to insert one and invoke it in the execution context of the web site.

Comment: Thanks , but the problem here is the exploitation payload

Comment: Any javascript exploit will work since you can execute arbitrary javascript.  If you are just looking for a pentest result, you already showed the site is insecure.